# How to programmatically make columns and rows fill an entire TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, controls, tablelayoutpanel

**Hello!**

I need to add buttons to a TableLayoutPanel, and I wish for these buttons to resize and align next to each other with no padding.
In order to do this I was thinking of making the TableLayoutPanel have auto-sized columns and simply set the size and width at runtime.

However, when I add these buttons at runtime, I get weird and unexpected results.
The results I am getting are as follows:

[image: RESULTS]

But the result I wish to have is as follows:

[image: WANTED RESULTS]

The form in visual has a simple TableLayoutPanel added to it with columns and rows set to automatic size. The rest is done via this code:

```
public partial class Editor : Form
{
    int gridWidth = 16;
    int gridHeight = 8;

    public Editor(int[] size)
    {
        gridWidth = size[0];
        gridHeight = size[1];
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButtonArray();
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = gridWidth;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = gridHeight;
    }

    private void CreateButtonArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                //b.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                b.Text = $"{j},{i}";
                b.Click += b_Click;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b, j, i);
                b.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
                b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `Anchor`. `Dock` is enough for what you are doing.

Comment: Your TableLayoutPanel is added in the Designer. Does it have to fill a specific section of the Parent Form? Did you anchor it? Or is docked inside another Container (e.g., a Panel)? This is the default layout setting (nested Containers - this also helps a lot when setting up a DpiAware application) -- You said you want  no padding, but the image that describes the *desired result* shows quite a lot of padding that separates the Rows. Should it be *dynamic*? -- Note that you're setting Columns and Rows after the Buttons have been added to the TLP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your panel must fill the parent form. For that you should set the `Dock` property to fill.

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Then you must divide the width equally among the columns.

```
var width = 100f / tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;
foreach (ColumnStyle columnStyle in tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles)
{
    columnStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
    columnStyle.Width = Width;
}
```

And last you must devide height equally among the rows

```
var height = 100f / tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
foreach (RowStyle rowStyle in tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles)
{
    rowStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
    rowStyle.Height = height;
}
```

After these create your buttons and set their `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill`.

To avoid the distortion in the image you showed you have to clear your panel and add the columns and rows again. Here is an example

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = gridWidth;
var width = 100f / gridWidth;
for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, width));
}

tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = gridHeight;
var height = 100f / gridHeight;
for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, height));
}

for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
    {
        Button b = new Button()
        {
            Text = $"{j},{i}"
        };
        b.Click += b_Click;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b, j, i);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

Or simply your method `Editor_Load` should be

```
private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = gridWidth;
    var width = 100f / gridWidth;
    for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, width));
    }

    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = gridHeight;
    var height = 100f / gridHeight;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, height));
    }

    CreateButtonArray();
}
```

Comment: This worked wonders! 
It's obvious that Forms is a lot diffrent from what I initially thought it'd be..

Thank you for providing such a clear description that I can study!